# Export file to csv but when it wont show the file in django

Tags: python, django

So i try to export result of query into csv files, but when i do , it says success , but i dont see where is the file , or the file being download in the browser , i already search the file but i dont find it anywhere, here's the code

AJAX in html

```
 <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#export").click(function () {
        var urls = "{% url 'polls:export' %}";  
        var name = $('#columnselect').val();
        var table = $('#dataselect').val();
        var column = $('#conditionselect').val();
        var operator = $('#operator').val();
        var condition = $('#parameter').val();

        $.ajax({                     
          url: urls,                    
          data: {
            'name' : name,
            'table': table,
            'column' : column,
            'operator' : operator,
            'condition' : condition
          },
          success: function(data) {   
              alert("success"); 
          },
          error: function(data)
          {
            alert("error occured");
          }
        });
      });
      });

  </script>
```

urls.py

```
path('export/',views.export,name='export'),
```

views.py

```
def export(request):
    import cx_Oracle
    data_name = request.GET.get('name',1)
    table_name = request.GET.get('table',1)
    column_name = request.GET.get('column',1)
    operator = request.GET.get('operator',1)
    condition = request.GET.get('condition',1)
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('IP', 'PORT', sid='') 
    conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=r'', password='', dsn=dsn_tns) 
    c = conn.cursor() 
    c.execute("select "+data_name+" from "+table_name+" where "+column_name+operator+"'"+condition+"'")
    c.rowfactory = makeDictFactory(c)
    columnalldata = []
    for rowDict in c:
        columnalldata.append(rowDict[data_name])
    context = {
        'obj4' : columnalldata
    }
    response = HttpResponse(content_type ='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;filename="output.csv"'

    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(context)
    print(response)
    return response
```

can someone find where i am wrong here? i already follow the documentation too ..

Thankyou for the help

Comment: don't you get error message when you run in console/terminal ?

Comment: no , it perfectly working

Comment: this code try to send data back to client and it doesn't save it on disk. But I would write to row list, not dictionary.

Comment: any idea how to save it on disk @furas

Comment: to save on disk on server - you need `writer = csv.writer( open("output.csv", "w") )`

Comment: hmm what is "w" for ?

Comment: https://www.javatpoint.com/create-csv-with-django i follow this and it seems like it works without the open thing , or maybe there is something wrong with my ajax? because if success only return the alert?

Comment: @furas oh i see now!, w is for write , and the file is created , thankyouu

Comment: it opens local file on disk for writing ('w') and then it writes in this file. If file doesn't exist then it creates new one. If file exists then it removes previous content.